# On foreign key delete destroy child rows?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm pretty new to using foreign keys, and can't really find anything on the MySQL website. Here is my database structure:

```
hosts
    id
    etc.
events
    id
    host_id
    etc.
```

One or multiple `events` belong to a `host`. When the `host` is deleted I need all `events` attached to it to be deleted. How can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: So you didn't find the page on the MySQL web site on [Using Foreign Key constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html), that pops up as the first result when you search for _'mysql foreign key constraints'_?

Answer (score 0):

use case cade on delete properly

You can check details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)-